# Finding the infimum of the set $A=\left\{\cos(\pi \sqrt{n}/2)+2/n: n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

I wish to find the infimum of the set $A=\left\{\cos(\pi \sqrt{n}/2)+2/n\right\}$.

I've an attempt below, of which I'm not too confident. I'd appreciate if someone could check it or show me how to do it.  Proving there's no *greater* lower bound (and conversely no *lesser* upper bound) has been a struggle for me for some reason.

$|\cos(\pi \sqrt{n}/2)| \le 1$ we have $\displaystyle \cos(\pi \sqrt{n}/2)+\dfrac{2}{n} \ge -1+\frac{1}{n} \ge -1. $

So $-1$ is a lower bound for $A$ . To show that it's the greatest lower bound, we need to prove that $\epsilon-1$ is not a lower bound for any $\epsilon > 0$. I've tried what follows, but I'm not sure if it's correct:

Take $\displaystyle k = \lceil \frac{2}{\epsilon-1} \rceil+1$ then for all $n \ge k$, the number $n_0 = 4(2k+1)^2$

$\displaystyle \cos\left(\frac{\pi }{2} \sqrt{n_0}\right)+\frac{2}{n_0} = \cos\left((2k+1)\pi\right)+\frac{2}{4(2k+1)^2} = -1+\frac{2}{4(2k+1)^2} < \frac{2}{4(2k+1)^2} < \frac{2}{k} < \epsilon-1.$

Thus $\epsilon -1$ is not a lower bound of $A$. Hence  $\inf(A) = -1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative way:

Let $n = (2(2k+1))^2$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$,

then $\cos \left( \frac{\pi \sqrt{n}}{2}\right)+\frac{2}{n}= -1+\frac{2}{(2(2k+1))^2}$

$$\lim_{k \to \infty}-1+\frac{2}{(2(2k+1))^2}=-1$$

I have illustrated a subsequence that gets arbitrary close to $-1$, and $-1$ is the infimum.

Remark:

$$1 + \frac{2}{16k^2} < \frac{2}{16k^2}$$ is a false statement.

Comment: Thank you! I've confused where the cosine tends to be -1. I have edited it, is it better now? I haven't learned the subsequences idea yet. If a subsequence converges to a lower bound, does that mean it's the greatest lower bound?

Comment: I am using the idea that if $B \subset A$, then $\inf (B)  \ge inf(A)$. So we have $-1 \le \inf(A) \le \inf(B)=-1$.

Comment: Ah, I see! That's very nice! If you don't mind, please, could you check whether my attempted proof is correct now? I've used the same $n$ that you have used for the subsequence now. But the wording etc is probably wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: minor comments: $\forall n \ge k$ is not used thereafter, most likely you can remove it. You might want to write $n_k$ to show its dependency on $k$ as compared to $n_0$ thought it doesn't matter since you are just taking a particular $k$.